# cordova azure adal authentication redirec URI is set to file:///

Tags: android, cordova, azure-active-directory, adal

I am developing cordova app on android platform, I am using the adal library

Cordova azure adal authentication redirect URI is always set to

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

even though if I specifically specify as below

```
redirectUri: "https://localhost:44356/"
```

This problem is preventing me from enabling azure authentication on cordova mobile app for Azure platform.

Can anyone help with suggestions or comments ? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refer the sample reference for Azure Active Directory Authentication using ADAL Cordova plugin in the following document link and check the configuration steps.
Reference: [Azure ADAL Authentication for Cordova App Guidance](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cordova-docs/blob/master/articles/app-services/add-authentication.md)
Also, I would suggest you to check the steps mentioned in the below document for adding authentication to your Cordova Application.
[Add Authentication to the App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users)